# music playing script 12 errors

Tags: java

This is the part i think i am having the trouble on:

```
public class AudioPlayer {
    //play the music
    AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer([Optional Replay = true]);
    AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
    //stop the music
    AP.Stop();
}
```

Here's the error that I got:

> AudioPlayer.java:3: error: ')' expected AudioPlayer AP = new
>   AudioPlayer(optional Replay = true);
>                                            ^ AudioPlayer.java:3: error: illegal start of type AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer(optional Replay
>   = true);
>                                                    ^ AudioPlayer.java:3: error:  expected AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer(optional
>   Replay = true);
>                                                     ^ AudioPlayer.java:3: error: ';' expected AudioPlayer AP = new
>   AudioPlayer(optional Replay = true);
>                                                          ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error:  expected
>   AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
>              ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error:  expected AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
>                                    ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error: ';' expected AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
>                                     ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error: illegal start of type AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
>                                       ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error:  expected AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() +
>   "Music/2.wav");
>                                        ^ AudioPlayer.java:4: error: ';' expected AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
>                                                      ^ AudioPlayer.java:6: error:  expected AP.Stop();
>          ^ AudioPlayer.java:6: error: reached end of file while parsing AP.Stop();
>             ^ 12 errors Press any key to continue . . .`

Any ideas of what is happening? What is causing the error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: what kinds of parameters does the AudioPlayer class constructor take in?

Comment: What you have there is not valid syntax.  You just...can't do that in Java.  Are you trying to accept a boolean into that constructor instead?

Comment: class, interface, or enum

Comment: @jake in theory that is possible, but it's just weird syntax.  You may want to change AudioPlayer class to accept a different kind of parameter.

Comment: I've looked at this code a lot closer, and it's got some serious syntax issues.  First, you have a class called `AudioPlayer`, but you're calling methods on it that simply don't exist.  Where is your `AudioPlayer` coming from that has the `Stop` or `playSong` method on it?  Second, you need a method to do all of the work that you're trying to do in the class declaration - preferably `main` - since what you're trying to do there is invalid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing this line

```
AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer([Optional Replay = true]);
```

with this one:

```
boolean optionalReplay = true;
AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer(optionalReplay);
```

The program isn't understanding this statement: `[Optional Replay = true]`.  What I'm giving you is more Java-appropriate syntax.

FYI, I'm assuming that the AudioPlayer constructor takes in a Boolean parameter.  But I might be guessing wrong about the way you wrote your code.

Comment: thank you that fixed a big amount of the errors i am down to 8 errors now

Comment: Look at the code closer.  Doing just this won't fix the issue.

Comment: i managed to get it down to 4 errors          AudioPlayer.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public boolean optionalReplay = true;
       ^
AudioPlayer.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
AudioPlayer AP = new AudioPlayer(optionalReplay);
^
AudioPlayer.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
AP.playSong(signlink.findcachedir() + "Music/2.wav");
^
AudioPlayer.java:6: error: class, interface, or enum expected
AP.Stop();
^
4 errors
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @Makoto, standard debugging practice is to make one change at a time and fix the easiest bug.  You make one change at a time because you aren't as likely to introduce new errors, and you fix the easiest bug because this sometimes saves effort as a less obviously solvable bug is fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @jake with your new set of errors, it looks like you need to put all this code you've got into a method.